# dataGridView_CellClick event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

so I'm developing this windows form application, that let's users to pick from a **DataGridView8**. The **DataGridView8** has a **ButtonColumn**, so when you click the button te informations about the title in the button will appear on another ***DataGridView9***. It is linked to SQL-Server, and Already have a complete database. I'm just stuck on how to make the ButtonColumn work as If I click it, another items appear on the ***DataGridView9***.

this is the event for the `dataGridView8_CellClick`

```
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        DataGridViewButtonColumn buttonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        buttonColumn.Text = "id_fil";
        buttonColumn.Name = "id_fil1";
        buttonColumn.DataPropertyName = "id_fil";
        dataGridView8.Columns.Add(

        dataGridView8.Columns.Add("id", "id_fil");
        dataGridView8.Columns.Add("nom", "nom_fil");
        }


   private void dataGridView8_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
            e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            cnx.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select nom_module from module where id_module ='" + e.ColumnIndex +"'", cnx);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                dataGridView9.Rows.Add(dr[2]);
            }
            dr.Close();
            cnx.Close();
        }
    }
```

it's not pretty much detailed but It seems to work fine and show the items that I need from my database, But the ButtonColumn is what I don't know how to deal with...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you clicked on the button`s column with:

```
if(e.SelectedColumn == (your column index from 0))
```

Or the row:

```
e.SelectedRow
```

If the datagridview9 is binded to a dataset you can't change it's values(rows).In that case, you have to unbind it and change it`values,or it is better to write the whole c# code to fill the datagridview.